# Файл не грузится на сервер

Tags: php, html

Сразу код:

```
if ($_FILES) {
    $file_name     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_new_name = time() . '_' . $file_name;
    echo $file_name . '<br />' . $file_new_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], ROOT_DIR . '/uploads/mee/' . $file_name);
    rename(ROOT_DIR . '/uploads/mee/' . $file_name, ROOT_DIR . '/uploads/mee/' . $file_new_name);

    $db->query("INSERT INTO " . PREFIX . "_downloads (id, name, server_name, downloads) VALUES (NULL, '$file_name', '$file_new_name', '0')");
    $insert_id = $db->insert_id();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="action" />
</form>
```

Вот там есть `echo $file_name.'<br />'.$file_new_name;` - он выдает имя файла и его новое имя, как и должно быть => файл загружается в память. Но вот дальше файл не появляется в нужной папке. Вчера, вроде все работало, а сегодня вдруг перестало :) Да и не менял-то и ничего (опять - вроде).

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Файл не грузился из-за директивы upload_max_filesize в php.ini